# App size dramatically increased on iOS 12

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode10, ios12

I have 3 apps on the store. I have upgraded to iOS 12 and XCode 10 and uploaded my apps to the store. Each of my apps got 20-30 mb higher than previous versions.

Is it because I changed "`New build system`" to "`Legacy build`" or is it anything else?

PS: I changed back to `new build system` but its same. Anyone knows whats going on?

Comment: This might be because it need to support the Legacy also.